# React Native backgroundImage not working with element of flatlist

Tags: react-native

I try to call for my picture imageBackground an element of my flatlist, but i have this error message :

'invalid call'

If i do like this that work

```
<FlatList
                          horizontal={true}
                          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                          data={this.state.newDataCards}
                          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
                          renderItem={({item}) => {
                              const image =  './../assets/galaxy.jpg' // HERE ITS OK
                              return (

                                  <TouchableHighlight  onPress={() => alert(item.description)}>
                                     <View style={styles.card_container}>
                                            <ImageBackground source={require(image)} style={styles.card_image} imageStyle={{ borderRadius: 6, resizeMode: 'contain' }} >
                                           </ImageBackground>
                                     </View>
                                   </TouchableHighlight>

                              )
                          }
                      }
                  />
```

But if i try to get 'const image' with my item.url_img that don't work :

```
   <FlatList
                          horizontal={true}
                          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                          data={this.state.newDataCards}
                          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
                          renderItem={({item}) => {
                              const image =  item.url_img // HERE ITS NOT OK
                              return (

                                  <TouchableHighlight  onPress={() => alert(item.description)}>
                                     <View style={styles.card_container}>
                                            <ImageBackground source={require(image)} style={styles.card_image} imageStyle={{ borderRadius: 6, resizeMode: 'contain' }} >
                                           </ImageBackground>
                                     </View>
                                   </TouchableHighlight>

                              )
                          }
                      }
                  />
```

my item.url_img return : './../assets/galaxy.jpg'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the React Native [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/images#static-image-resources) says

```
// GOOD (this is correct)
<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />;

// BAD (this is wrong...)
var icon = this.props.active
  ? 'my-icon-active'
  : 'my-icon-inactive';
<Image source={require('./' + icon + '.png')} />;

// GOOD (this is correct)
var icon = this.props.active
  ? require('./my-icon-active.png')
  : require('./my-icon-inactive.png');
<Image source={icon} />;
```

So, I suppose your `this.state.newDataCards` looks like this -

```
[
  {
    id:1,
    url_img : './../assets/galaxy.jpg'
  },
  {
    id:2,
    url_img : './../assets/galaxy.jpg'
  },
  .
  . and so on
]
```

Change your `this.state.newDataCards` this to

```
[
  {
    id:1,
    url_img : require('./../assets/galaxy.jpg'),
  },
  {
    id:2,
    url_img : require('./../assets/galaxy.jpg'),
  },
  .
  . and so on
]
```

And your `FlatList` to this

```
<FlatList
    horizontal={true}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    data={this.state.newDataCards}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
    renderItem={({ item }) => {
      return (
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => alert(item.description)}>
          <View style={styles.card_container}>
            <ImageBackground
              source={item.url_img}
              style={styles.card_image}
              imageStyle={{
                borderRadius: 6,
                resizeMode: 'contain',
              }}></ImageBackground>
          </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      );
    }}
  />
```

Comment: Indeed that was that . Missing this in the docs, thank you !!